# react-native-navigation is backwards on iOS device

Tags: ios, react-native, navigation, react-native-navigation

Strange situation here, and google can't seem to find me the answer.  I have a small (i.e. 'hello world') application done in react-native for iOS and I am finding that what renders in the simulator is quite different than what renders on my device itself.

**Simulator (expected behavior):**

Here is what the simulator displays (and is what I expect): [List View on the Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRdjA.png)

And here is what I see if I edit an entry (also expected): [Details View on the Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kgnD.png)

**Device (unexpected behavior):**

When I view this same code on my device, I see the following:
[List View on my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01kcf.png)

And editing an entry looks like this: [Details View on my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnTZL.png)

Does anyone know what's going on with the navigation?   It happens even with a default expo project built from scratch.  Here is my App.js file where I handle the navigation:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import BrandListScreen from './components/BrandListScreen';
import BrandDetailScreen from './components/BrandDetailScreen';
import BrandAddScreen from './components/BrandAddScreen';
import BrandEditScreen from './components/BrandEditScreen';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    BrandList: BrandListScreen,
    BrandDetails: BrandDetailScreen,
    BrandAdd: BrandAddScreen,
    BrandEdit: BrandEditScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'BrandList',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#777777'
      },
      headerTintColor: '#FFF',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
    },
  },
);

const App = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default App;
```

I certainly do appreciate the second set of eyes on this, as I'm stumped.  (And I'm happy to be told that I'm missing something obvious.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should check the region of your device in Settings and also the language set. If your device language is set to a language that is read from right to left, iPhone renders its UI accordingly.

Comment: That's great advice, but I just checked the region and language settings on my device and they are as expected (iPhone Language: English, Region: United States).  Strange.